# update view's property isn't useful in method `withStartAction`

Tags: android

```
       v.animate()
        .withStartAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                v.setScaleX(0.8f);
                v.setScaleY(1.5f);
            }
        })
        .scaleX(1)
        .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                v.setScaleX(0.3f);
            }
        }).setDuration(500).start();
```

I hava a example above, when I run it, `v.setScaleX(0.8f)` isn't work but `v.setScaleY(1.5f)` is avaliable. I think because I invoke `.scaleX(1)` ! If I change `.scaleX(1)` to `.scaleY(1)` , result reverse. So can someon give me idea to reslove it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you should using this way

create animation x y function:

```
void animationXY(View v, float scaleX, float scaleY, long duration,
        @Nullable Runnable endAction) {
    v.animate()
            .scaleX(scaleX)
            .scaleY(scaleY)
            .setDuration(duration)
            .withEndAction(endAction)
            .start();
}
```

and call

```
animationXY(v, 0.8f, 1.5f, 250, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                animationXY(v, 1f, 1.5f, 250, new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        v.setScaleX(0.3f);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: yeh, thanks. But I just want to how it can't work. It's a internal bug for Google?

Comment: its not a bug, in document, the start action is  "The action to run when the next animation starts", that why v.setScaleX(0.8f); seem not working

Comment: But why I can change `scaleY(1.5f)` success?

Comment: because you can not set scaleX in the same time, but not problem with scaleY.

Comment: For this reason,I look for source but no idea. it has no limit for change `scaleX`